# Activity launch from Notification

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, notifications

I have an ListActivity with a Listview containing details of Alarm objects. When the app is not open and an Alarm occurs (the app uses AlarmManager to be woken at time chosen by the user) a notification appears which when clicked launches the ListActivity and passes the Alarm object to it.

The ListActivity checks for an Alarm object in onCreate and if present will highlight the correct ListItem to signify which alarm has just occurred. All of this works well.

I would like to do something similar when the ListActivity is already in the foreground. I have added single_top to the Notification's Intent so I don't get a new ListActivity on top of the existing one. But the problem is that onCreate or onResume do not get called, so I have no opportunity to check for a passed Alarm object.

Is there a way to achieve the effect I want? Am I missing a lifecycle method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing lifecycle method is `onNewIntent`.